# User does not have purchase receipt in device

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-app purchase in my app & one of my users faced an issue where,

1. The user haven't added a card to her apple id.
2. She goes to buy subscription, device shows her pop up saying the card has not been attached to the id & subscription fails.
3. Then she continues with adding the card.
4. After adding the card it shows that the subscription is successful.

I have a code where it only checks if the device has a purchase receipt & if it has, then it updates our server with it. But seems like it doesn't have a purchase receipt. I'm stuck at this issue for more than a week now & it seems going no where yet.

Comment: You should always include a "restore purchases" button in your app; that way the user can easily refresh the receipt and restore any subscriptions or non-consumable purchases.

Comment: @Paulw11 But its a renewable subscription so we don't need a restore button for renewable. Plus restore is used to restore the subscription in case user changes his phone, but thats not the case here. Thanks !!

Comment: I always put a restore button, since it makes it easier for situations, such as you mentioned, where the user installs the app on a new device. If you had a restore button then you wouldn't be facing the issue you are now. The user would have tapped restore and been on their way

Comment: You also need to ensure that your purchasing code correctly handles pending transactions when the app launches.